# Lauching vbscript from HTML file

Tags: html, vbscript

Good day,

This may sound a simple question but im a beginner in this so any help is really appreciated.

I have a vbscript that will launch a website from IE with the address bar disabled. This works fine when i execute a .vbs file.

The question i have is, can this script be inserted in a HMTL file and the same action be performed?

Meaning when i click a HTML file, IE is lauched with a particular website with the address bar being disable.

This is my vbscript code :

```
Set oIE1 = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")

oIE1.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com"
oIE1.Visible = 1
oIE1.AddressBar = 0
oIE1.StatusBar = 0
oIE1.ToolBar = 0
oIE1.MenuBar = 0
```

How do i insert this inside a html file?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Jvarman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just... put it in an HTML page. You're going to get security warnings, of course, since client-side scripts are not allowed (by default) to instantiate COM/ActiveX objects like you're trying to do.

```
<html>

<script language="vbscript">
    Sub LoadIE()
        Set oIE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        oIE1.Visible = True
        oIE1.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com"
    End Sub
</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Launch IE" onclick="LoadIE()">
</body>

</html>
```